# calling method from action of controller in emberjs

Tags: ember.js

for example i have a controller like this :

```
App.theController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  methodA:funtcion() {},
  actions: {
    methodB:function(){},
    methodC:function(){}
  }
});
```

my questions is :

1. How can methodB call methodC
2. How can methodA call methodB

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You have to use `this.send([methodName])` in order to get your methods called correctly:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    console.log('App ready');
    var theController = App.theController.create();
    theController.send('methodC');
  }
});

App.theController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  methodA:function(){
    //How can methodA calling methodB
    this.send('methodB');
    console.log('methodA called');
  },
  actions:{
    methodB:function(){
      //How can methodB calling methodC
      this.send('methodC');
      console.log('methodB called');
    },
    methodC:function(){
      console.log('methodC called');
    }
  }
});
```

Here a simple [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ELOSiS/2/edit) as a playground.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but I don't manage to update my app. I need to call the actions, but they return something. see http://jsbin.com/OreraGE/1/edit It's probably simple, but I'm blocked here...

Comment: @sly7_7 currently AFK will look at it as soon I get home :)

Comment: @sly7_7, It looks like playing with actions is a oneway thing, meaning no return value is passed along, to make it work tough you could define the method directly on the object and outside the actions hash, and invoke the method directly with `this.methodC()` see here what I mean by that: http://jsbin.com/eBegIPAy/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for investigating. After digging in our app code, I realize it was for test purpose, so I just changed the way of testing. If I have other use cases, I think actually your workaround is the only possible way of doing it. I think it was an assumed trade off when switching to this implementation. I'll ask it to @lukemelia though, because I think it is not as unusual.

Comment: As an matter of best practices, `this.send` should be used in the handling of some user/event-generated "action" (often implicitly by way of the `{{action}}` helper). It should not be used as a general way of calling methods.

If you need to call code that is in an action handler from a non-action context, extract it into its own method and delegate to it from both the action handler context and the other context.

Comment: @LukeMelia can you create a sample in jsbin . thanks.