# Calling controller method from controller action in Ember 2.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Ember 2.0 is really giving me a hard time to understand the new functionality. I want to call a method in the controller from the action function, but dont seem to find a way how. Wasted some time on this already

I have read this: [calling method from action of controller in emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075263/calling-method-from-action-of-controller-in-emberjs) but it is only working for Ember 1.x as in Ember 2.0 there is no ArrayController anymore and I cannot use this.send().

Basically what I would need is:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   methodFunction: function(data) {
      console.log("YEY", data);
   }
   actions: {
      sessionAction: function(data) {
          this.methodFunction(data);
      }
   }
});
```

Problem is that `this.methodFunction` is not available

Comment: [Check out this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/puyufebeqo/2/edit?html,js,console,output), your example is absolutly working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code you've provided in question has an error:

> SyntaxError: controllerName.js: unknown: Unexpected token (7:3)(…)

You're missing `,` after `methodFunction` declaration. Fix:

```
App.SomeController = Ember.Controller.extend({
   methodFunction: function(data) {
      console.log("YEY", data);
   },
   actions: {
      sessionAction: function(data) {
          this.methodFunction(data);
      }
   }
});
```

For template:

```
<button {{action 'sessionAction' 'Example data'}}>Send session action</button>
```

It logs correctly:

> YEY Example data

By the way, you can also take advantage of ES2015 syntax:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   methodFunction(data) {
      console.log("YEY", data);
   },
   actions: {
      sessionAction(data) {
          this.methodFunction(data);
      }
   }
});
```

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/6dbad6704a62d3617901)
- [Full code behind demo.](http://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/6dbad6704a62d3617901)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive response. It is indeed working. In my case the call was actually coming from `window` object thus, `this` was pointing to window, not ember object